# ViewPager and Fragments: Why do I always see the same thing?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have created a ViewPager with three "pages". The code is this

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_tab_strip);
        FragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);
        pagerTabStrip.setDrawFullUnderline(true);
        pagerTabStrip.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    }

}
```

MyFragmentPageAdapter.java

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private String[] pageTitle = {
            "Page1", "Page2", "Page3"
    };

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new PageFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString("pageIndex", Integer.toString(position + 1));
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pageTitle.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return pageTitle[position];
    }

}
```

PageFragment.java

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, null);

    return view;

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33B5E5"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:text="@string/inf" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/ben" />

                <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Prova"
         />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/verifica" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But now i visualize in all three pages the same thing. If I for example on page 2 I want a TextView with the text "This is the 2 page" and on the third page a TextView with the text "This is the page 3" and in the first page  two TextView with the button ... how can I? I'm going crazy, please let pass me the code to do this thing. Please.

Answer (score 2):

Once you inflate `PageFragment`'s layout you need to get a reference of the `TextView` so you can display the position on it via the `Bundle` you are passing using `setArguments()`. Use your `view` variable inside `onCreateView()` to get a reference of the `TextView`. (i.e. `view.findViewById()`). Then use `getArguments()` in your `PageFragment` to retrieve the `Bundle` with that has position, and set the `TextView` to that value.

Answer (score 1):

[this](http://www.ovidiuconeac.ro/2012/08/17/horizontal-view-swiping/) is a good example for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function in your page fragment class to configure elements and modify onCreateView to attach childs.

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

        TextView tv1 ;
        // ...

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, null);
            /// Attach your childs
            tv1 = view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        return view;

        }

        public void configure(int position) {
            tv1 .setText("This is "+ position);
        }
    }
```

Then just call the function configure in getItem function

```
  @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            PageFragment fr = new PageFragment();
            fr.configure(position + 1);         
            return fr;
        }
```

Comment: What if I want to add anything else? For example the button etc.. I should not create a layout for each page xml?

Comment: What do you mean ? A different Layout per page ? Or the same Layout ?
Futhermore, I just noticed my answer is wrong. [Emmanuel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2029566/emmanuel)  answer is better .
You should pass arguments via bundle.

Comment: Yes, a different layout for each page I mean. How do you do that? What should I change?

Comment: You will have to create several layouts if the layouts are significantly different. If you just want to change the text on a `TextView` you do not need another xml. If you do need significantly different layouts just create a new `Fragment` and inflate a different layout in `onCreateView()`

Comment: You are already doing it. Just crate a new `Class` that extends `Fragment` and inflate another layout, like you are doing. Then on `getView()` put a `switch` statement around `position` and depending on the `position` value instantiate the specific `Fragment` you want